# (Android) Is safe to save resource in static final constant? (Now resource is not static final)

Tags: android, android-resources

After ADT 14, R class value is no more "static final int" it just "static int".
And I want use constant as "static final". like below

```
public static final int exampleNameId = R.string.exampleName;
```

After run application, if android system want to change R.string.exampleName can be problem. because exampleNameId is final So System can't change value.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: you will need to add source code for `Area` class

Comment: What do you mean by `point array of borderArea`? Please add your Shape and Rectangle class and explain more on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Not sure how this could be turned into an answer, except for copy+paste of the code, but I once added this as one of many utility methods in one of my libs: https://github.com/javagl/Geom/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/geom/Shapes.java#L118

Comment: If shape is rectagle then you have it right there. If shape is arbitrary you have to resort to image processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have anything that implements the `Shape` interface (e.g. `Polygon`).  You can get the `PathIterator` for that shape which provide the `outline` with a configurable degree of granularity.

The following example gets a `flattened` PathIterator to avoid having to deal with `Bezier curves` and just use `drawLine` to reproduce the outline.  Since there were no gaps in the drawing, I didn't have to worry about using the the actual iterator commands to reposition the start and stop drawing locations (i.e pen up and pen down, etc).

To fully understand this you will need to read about some of these methods in the Java API documentation.

```java
    import java.awt.BasicStroke;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
    import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class Outline extends JPanel {

       JFrame       frame = new JFrame();
       PathIterator iter;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Outline().start());
       }

       public void start() {
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.add(this);
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          demo();
       }

       public void demo() {
          double smajAxis = 200;
          double sminAxis = 100;
          Ellipse2D.Double oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(250 - smajAxis / 2,
                            250 - sminAxis / 2, smajAxis, sminAxis);
          iter = oval.getPathIterator(null, .02);
          repaint();

       }
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
          g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
          double[] start = new double[2];
          double[] end = new double[2];
          iter.currentSegment(start);
          int x1 = (int) start[0];
          int y1 = (int) start[1];
          int savex1 = x1;
          int savey1 = y1;
          iter.next();
          while (!iter.isDone()) {
             iter.currentSegment(end);
             int x2 = (int) end[0];
             int y2 = (int) end[1];
             g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
             x1 = x2;
             y1 = y2;
             iter.next();
          }
          g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, savex1, savey1);

       }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. this is better than i wanted. :)